# custom `id` name using `insertGetId` fluent method of Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fluent-interface

According to Laravel's documentation:[Inserts](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#inserts)

> Note: When using PostgreSQL the insertGetId method expects the auto-incrementing column to be named "id".

So, is there a workaround for a custom `id` name while using `inserGetId`. i.e.

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Eloquent method `Model::create()` to return the object inserted, and obtain the object id, whatever his name is.

Try this:

```
$user = User::create(['email'=>'john@ecample.com','votes'=>0]);
$id = $user->custom_id;
```

This works if your User model is like:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
   //This custom_id column needs to be of type serial in your table
   protected $primaryKey = 'custom_id';
   protected $fillable = ['email','votes']; 
   //...more code ...     
}
```

I hope this works for you